# How to check if class doesn't exist in element

Tags: puppeteer

I have the following code:

```
<div class="ProductSize-group">
  <div class="c-form-field c-form-field--radio c-form-field--disabled c-form-field--unavailable ProductSize"><label for="input_radio_size_060" aria-hidden="true" class=""><span class="c-form-label-content">06.0</span></label><input name="size" aria-label="Size 06.0, out of stock" id="input_radio_size_060" type="radio" disabled="" required="" value="06.0"></div>
  <div class="c-form-field c-form-field--radio c-form-field--disabled c-form-field--unavailable ProductSize"><label for="input_radio_size_065" aria-hidden="true" class=""><span class="c-form-label-content">06.5</span></label><input name="size" aria-label="Size 06.5, out of stock" id="input_radio_size_065" type="radio" disabled="" required="" value="06.5"></div>
</div>
```

This is just part of it.  I need to check if this div contains class

```
<div class="c-form-field c-form-field--radio c-form-field--disabled c-form-field--unavailable ProductSize">
```

Specifically check if this div contains class `c-form-field--unavailable`

This is what I have:

```
  const productSizeOptions = await page.$(".ProductSize-group");
  productSizeOptions.map(productSizeOption => {

  })
```

But I can't figure out how to loop through each class to see if it exists in the element or not.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `:not`

```
await page.$(".ProductSize-group:not(.c-form-field--unavailable)");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```js
const foo = await page.$('.foo');

const hasBarClass = await page.evaluate(
  element => element.classList.contains('bar'),
  foo
);

if (!hasBarClass) console.log('Element.foo has no .bar class.');
```